# Showing off responsive design in action using animation

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, portfolio

I came across a very nice piece of functionality to show off responsive design in action. Please head to the "Show off on any device" section of [this page](http://www.guru.com/pro/new_profiles.aspx) (towards the bottom of the page).

Question: are they using some known plugin / downloadable piece of code / some sort of public snippet, or shall I have to replicate this from scratch myself if I want to get the same thing on my portfolio site?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replicate that with Bootstrap:

http://getbootstrap.com/

But I'm sure there are a few other frameworks around.

Answer (score 0):

I found something similar to what you were looking for here http://ivaldi.github.io/prezento/

I realise this question was asked a year ago but I thought I'd include my answer just in case someone stumbles upon it.